# Use fileupload as template field in a details view

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

I have an admin page where a user will select a document path and add that path to a certain column of a database. I am using a fileupload on the page where they can find the document and copy the path and then paste it into the details view. However, I want to skip this step and I want them to select a document and automatically make the path show up in the details view.

```
  <asp:FileUpload ID="FileUpload1" runat="server" Visible="False" Width="384px" /><br />
        <br />
        <div>
          <asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanel1" runat="server" UpdateMode="Conditional">

                <ContentTemplate>
                     <center>   <asp:DetailsView ID="DetailsView1" runat="server" AllowPaging="True" AutoGenerateRows="False"
                        DataKeyNames="ID" DataSourceID="SqlDataSource1" Height="128px" Width="544px" Visible="False" OnModeChanged="Button2_Click" CellPadding="4" ForeColor="#333333" GridLines="None" >
                        <Fields>
                                                    <asp:BoundField DataField="Order" HeaderText="Order" SortExpression="Order" />
                            <asp:BoundField DataField="Department" HeaderText="Department" SortExpression="Department"/>
                            <asp:BoundField DataField="DOC_Type" HeaderText="DOC_Type" SortExpression="DOC_Type" />
                            <asp:BoundField DataField="Title" HeaderText="Title" SortExpression="Title" />
                            <asp:BoundField DataField="Revision" HeaderText="Revision" SortExpression="Revision" />
                            <asp:BoundField DataField="DOC" HeaderText="DOC" SortExpression="DOC" />
                            <asp:BoundField DataField="Active" HeaderText="Active" SortExpression="Active" />
                            <asp:BoundField DataField="Rev_Date" HeaderText="Rev_Date" SortExpression="Rev_Date" />
                            <asp:BoundField DataField="ID" HeaderText="ID" InsertVisible="False" ReadOnly="True"
                                SortExpression="ID" Visible="False" />
                            <asp:CommandField ShowInsertButton="True" />
                        </Fields>
                        <FooterStyle BackColor="#5D7B9D" BorderStyle="None" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="White" />
                        <CommandRowStyle BackColor="#E2DED6" BorderStyle="None" Font-Bold="True" />
                        <RowStyle BackColor="#F7F6F3" BorderStyle="None" ForeColor="#333333" />
                        <FieldHeaderStyle BackColor="#E9ECF1" BorderStyle="None" Font-Bold="True" />
                        <EmptyDataRowStyle BorderStyle="None" />
                        <PagerStyle BackColor="#284775" BorderStyle="None" ForeColor="White" HorizontalAlign="Center" />
                        <HeaderStyle BackColor="#5D7B9D" BorderStyle="None" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="White" />
                        <InsertRowStyle BorderStyle="None" />
                        <EditRowStyle BackColor="#999999" BorderStyle="None" />
                        <AlternatingRowStyle BackColor="White" BorderStyle="None" ForeColor="#284775" />
                    </asp:DetailsView>
                         &nbsp;
                    <br />
```

I need to get the fileupload1 into the DOC contenttemplate area so instead of showing an empty textbox it will show just a textbox it will show the fileupload
[image]

[image]

Comment: I can't get the file upload inside the details view

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if this helps, but it is a start:

```
<asp:TemplateField HeaderText="DOC">
    <InsertItemTemplate>
        <asp:FileUpload ID="FileUploadDOC" runat="server" Width="384px" />
    </InsertItemTemplate>
</asp:TemplateField>
```

In Codebehind you can set the doc-path in the following way:

```
Private Sub DetailsView1_ItemInserting(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.Web.UI.WebControls.DetailsViewInsertEventArgs) Handles DetailsView1.ItemInserting
    Dim FileUploadDOC As FileUpload = DirectCast(Me.DetailsView1.FindControl("FileUploadDOC"), FileUpload)
    e.Values("DOC") = FileUploadDOC.PostedFile.FileName
End Sub
```

Comment: i tryed that before and it didnt work but this time it did. I guess i was placing it in the wrong place. However, now the location is correct but when i update the database the value is blank

Comment: What do you mean with "the value is blank"? A FileUpload control is always blank, you can't set it's value(for security reasons). It gets it's value from the user. You could use a Label in ItemTemplate, a Label+FileUpload-control aside in EditItemTemplate and a FileUpload-control in InsertItemTemplate.

Comment: hmm what i want in a sense is them to pick a file and the path of that file will be saved in the DOC column.  just the path not the actual file. When i click the fileupload and pick a file the path is shown in the textbox, when i hit insert in my detailsview, the doc field is empty

Comment: The path should be saved in the DOC column immediately when the user select it with the FileUpload or when he hits insert/save? What do you mean with "doc field is empty"? The field in your database or the fileupload-control? The fileupload is empty after a postback and you can't avoid that, therefor i recommended to use a combi of fileupload and Label.

Comment: I think your main problem is how to set the path so that it gets automatically updated/inserted in the database. Edited my answer.

Comment: i can post another pic or use ctrl +

Comment: Have you tried my suggestion "e.Values("DOC") = FileUploadDOC.PostedFile.FileName"? When does the "Object-Reference not set to an instance of object" Exception comes? Have you debugged it?

Comment: it comes up when i click insert to import the data into my database

Comment: i am using exactly what you ahve in the comment

Comment: Have you debugged it? Is the FileUpload control nothing or where exactly does the error occur? Set a breakpoint in the code i posted.